# NodeJS access variable from mongodb & write to JSON file

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I need to write a field from my mongodb database to a json file. Using node js. How to go about it? I haven't found anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var exportDocuments = function (db, callback) {
    // Get the documents collection 
    var collection = db.collection('documents');
    // Find some documents 
    collection.find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        require('fs').writeFile('yourFileName.json', JSON.stringify(docs), function (error) {
            if (error) return callback(error);
            callback();
        });
    });
}
```